# Box2D: how can I get same physics simulation if I use slow motion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, simulation, physics, box2d

I have a functional personal 2D game engine that uses Box2D. I am trying to implement fast and slow motion effects for my physics simulation. The fast motion I implemented by calling the `Step` function more frequently. This way, I get same simulation result no matter how fast I increase the physics update rate. However, the problem lies when I slow down the simulation. If I use the same technique, the simulation provides same result, but it looks like the frames dropped due to physics not updating as frequent, which is expected, but not what I am looking for.

I tried implementing a new way to update the physics world by stepping the world by `updateRate * timeScale` if timeScale is less than 1. It fixed the laggy updates, but now my simulation provides a different result compared to the ones with time scales of 1 or above.

I am looking to get the same simulation results for a time scale of 1, any number above 1, and any number below 1 and have the simulation still look smooth for slow motion. This is the code I have for reference.

```
    bool slowMotion = false;

    float physicsScaledTimeFactor = Time::getPhysicsScaledTimeFactor();
    if (physicsScaledTimeFactor >= 1) {
        float deltaUpdateTime = Time::getTimeRunningF() - Time::getPhysicsLoopRunTimeF();
        if (deltaUpdateTime < physicsTimeStep / physicsScaledTimeFactor)
            return;
    }
    else {
        slowMotion = true;
        float deltaUpdateTime = Time::getTimeRunningF() - Time::getPhysicsLoopRunTimeF();
        if (deltaUpdateTime < physicsTimeStep)
            return;
    }
    Time::updatePhysicsLoop

    // Update / step physics world
    if (slowMotion) 
        physicsWorld->Step(physicsTimeStep * physicsScaledTimeFactor, physicsVelocityIterations, physicsPositionIterations);
    else
        physicsWorld->Step(physicsTimeStep, physicsVelocityIterations, physicsPositionIterations);
```

Here is how the simulation result for time scales of 1 or above look like:
[image]
Here is how the simulation result for time scales of less than 1 look like:
[image]
As you can see, the squares end up in different positions. Is there a way to get same simulation results with the provided quality conditions or is this acceptable and leave it like that?

Update:
I checked other engines and they also contain the laggy effect. But, would there be a way to get same simulation results? The slow motion effect look very smooth and would be nice to have it work as expected.

Comment: I'd guess the easiest way would be to use a faster update rate then use the same rate at all speeds (assuming the fast speed can handle the faster update rate). Otherwise i guess you could use the slower rate and interpolate between frames

Comment: When you decrease time-step size, you get less error. So it must be the time-slow version that is right. To make the "fast time" versions right, you could increase update numbers (like keeping time step constant, just changing number of steps per frame-per-second)